# Reset Flask render_template output

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm currently making a parser for the battlefy website to quickly pull results and convert them to wikicode.

Website: http://tomshoe02.pythonanywhere.com/scraper

Example of it in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBlGE.png

Sample link to be parsed: https://dtmwra1jsgyb0.cloudfront.net/stages/6000c862d9155d46db7f41ca/rounds/1/matches

full app.py: https://pastebin.com/J2nsfmFa

app.py code snippet:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/lol", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/scraper", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def scraper():
    form = BattlefyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = form.matchhistory.data
        result = jloader(url)
        '''
        #result = url
        result = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable,
            "{}/stuff.py".format(directory), url]).decode('iso-8859-1')
        '''
        return render_template("scraper.html", form=form, result=result)
    return render_template("scraper.html", form=form)
```

Every time I submit without reloading the web app, the new results display among the old results. Is there a module I can use to clear the session cache and reset the state of the website without having to entirely reload the app every time I submit a new URL to be parsed?

Comment: "Every time I submit without reloading the web app,". I was under the impression that a form submission automatically causes a page reload by default, no?

Comment: Maybe it does? But it seems to keep the same output regardless. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong in the python function itself.

Comment: Is it possible that you use global variables in ```jloader(url)```?

Comment: @ThomasC Maybe I am not seeing it, but I just used the url for your site, to search
https://dtmwra1jsgyb0.cloudfront.net/stages/6000c862d9155d46db7f41ca/rounds/3/matches 
and https://dtmwra1jsgyb0.cloudfront.net/stages/6000c862d9155d46db7f41ca/rounds/3/matches
The results returned are completely different

Comment: @AkibRhast try your link and https://dtmwra1jsgyb0.cloudfront.net/stages/6000c862d9155d46db7f41ca/rounds/4/matches without refreshing the page

Comment: @Detlef I am using globals. https://github.com/TomShoe/parsing-website/blob/main/main/stuff.py Would that throw it off?

Comment: The way you are handling the form submission is what's causing the issue. Since you are not redirecting after handling the form submission. The data from the previous submission stays. From looking at your site, I am assuming you do NOT want to cause a page reload. As such what you actually want to do is handle form submission using ajax via javascript,

Comment: @ThomasC   I'm sorry, I haven't had enough time to give you a more detailed answer. I have now expanded my answer. I also think my code can still be revised. As you try to improve your code based on the answers given, you will surely notice a few helpful phrases and practices.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Akib. It doesn't matter whether a redirect is carried out after the form data has been received or the entire page is re-rendered and sent as a response from the server.
After each call, regardless of whether via POST or GET request, the entire page is reloaded and rendered. This could be reduced using ajax. However, this does not cause your issue.

The problem is not within your route, but within your `stuff.py` module.
You use global variables to save the results extracted from the loaded JSON files in lists.
The first solution would be to empty these lists every time
`jloader(url)` is called. But that doesn't completely solve the problem.
If several users start calls at the same time, this would lead to unexpectedly incorrect results. Since the previous request could not be completed if the list were emptied again and filled with further results.
In addition, global variables should be avoided as long as they are not absolutely necessary.
Because of the reasons listed, I advise you not to use the global variables and
to keep the lists as local variables within the function, which are kept for each
request and are returned at the end.

This is an approach how you could make your code clearer and do without global variables. I have only rewritten excerpts of your code. I think you can add the rest yourself.

```
import requests
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime
import gspread

class Match(namedtuple('Match', ['team_a', 'team_b', 'score_a', 'score_b'])):

    @property
    def winner(self):
        if self.score_a > self.score_b:
            return self.team_a
        elif self.score_a < self.score_b:
            return self.team_b
        return None

    def fmt(self):
        return '{{'\
            f'MatchSchedule|team1={self.team_a}|team2={self.team_b}'\
            f'|team1score={self.score_a}|team2score={self.score_b}'\
            f'|winner={self.winner}|date=...|time=...|timezone=PST|'\
            'dst=yes|vod1=|stream='\
            '}}'

def _get(data, key_path, default=None):
    tmp = data
    for k in key_path.split('.'):
        try:
            tmp = tmp[k]
        except KeyError:
            return default
    return tmp


def get_matches(url, team_alias={}):
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    for item in data:
        top_team = _get(item, 'top.name', _get(item, 'top.team.name'))
        low_team = _get(item, 'bottom.name', _get(item, 'bottom.team.name'))
        top_score = _get(item, 'top.score')
        low_score = _get(item, 'bottom.score')

        # Test for results that are None and react accordingly. 
        # The date and time queries are missing here. 

        top_team = team_alias.get(top_team, top_team)
        low_team = team_alias.get(low_team, low_team)

        match = Match(top_team, low_team, top_score, low_score)
        yield(match)

def get_teams():
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename='credentials.json')
    sh = gc.open_by_key('1N7wnIRWJRbULKychJU-EOyisuZBX1rgXwdW91Keki4M')

    col_name = worksheet.col_values(1)
    col_alias = worksheet.col_values(2)

    return dict(zip(col_name, col_alias))

def load_data(url):
    '''Use this instead of jloader(url).'''
    team_alias = get_teams()
    return '\n'.join(match.fmt() for match in get_matches(url, team_alias))

def main():
    url = 'https://dtmwra1jsgyb0.cloudfront.net/groups/5f60cffb30d29b119e36b42b/matches'
    dat = load_data(url)
    print(dat)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
``
```

Comment: I see, so the global variables are being saved and appended on each time I run the function, which is causing these problems. I'll study your code and refactor.